# Python Web Scraping and Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am relatively new to Python and completely new to webscraping, but I am trying to gather data from this website:

https://www.usclimatedata.com/climate/cumming/georgia/united-states/usga1415

I wanna grab the info from the tables from Jan-Dec and put it into a Pandas data frame and print it back to the user. I plan on doing some more stuff with the data like computing my own averages and mean/medians etc., but I am struggling with getting the data initially. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Hey Charlie, what have you tried so far? You may want to look into using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to get started with the web scraping part. For that, you'll obviously need to know some basic HTML and where the data you want is being stored. Once you've scraped it, you then want to sort the data in a way that's compatible with pandas dataframe. Hope that's enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

if you getting data from files ,you can use (x=pd.read_csv or put the file  extension that u use  instead of csv )and print(x)

Answer (score 0):

First check terms of website services in robots.txt to check whether it is legal to **scrape** the web page.

If it is, then you can use **bs4**'s **BeautifulSoup** package to **scrape** the web page.

```
def get_state_holiday_data(self, year: int, state_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    try:
        pagecontent = self.get_page_content(year, state_name)
        holiday_table_list = []
        for table in pagecontent.findAll("table"):
            for tbody in table.findAll("tbody"):
                for row in tbody.findAll("tr"):
                    holiday_row_list = []
                    if len(row.findAll("td")) == 3:
                        for cell_data in row.findAll("td"):
                            holiday_row_list.append(cell_data.find(text=True).replace('\n', '').strip(' '))
                        holiday_table_list.append(holiday_row_list)
            break
        state_holiday_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(holiday_table_list, columns=['Date', 'Day', 'Holiday'])
        state_holiday_df['Date'] = state_holiday_df['Date'].apply(
            lambda date: str(year) + '-' + datetime.strptime(date, '%d %b').strftime('%m-%d'))
        del state_holiday_df['Day']
        return state_holiday_df
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

Above is the sample code to **scrape** a table and convert it to dataframe, where **table** and **tbody** are the html table element id/name.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ not scrap